# Stationary Distribution of 2 step chain random walk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

In the question above, I understand everything up until the last 3 lines when it mentions the mean hitting time of the 2 step chain. Why does this tend to 2/M?

Does it have something to do with spending half it's time up and half it's time down or vice versa?

Any helpful advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because, as one can check in one line, the uniform distribution on the even vertices (which are the M/2 vertices the 2-step chain lives on) is stationary for this chain.